# Find string and return a different string in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, string, openpyxl

I've been trying to figure away to find a string inside a file, and then return the string 9 cells below it.  I'm not sure if I'm on the right path here, or totally off.  TFile consists of one column.   IF StringFound is where I'm stuck, I just know i'm trying to return the string 9 cells below the first string. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
import openpyxl as xl 
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

input_dir = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\NNM'
T = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\T.xlsx'


files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_dir)
         if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".xlsx")]

for file in files: 
   input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
   wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
   ws1=wb1.worksheets[0]

   TFile=pd.read_excel(T, usecols="B")
   String=pd.read_excel(input_file, usecols="A",nrows=1,header=None,squeeze=True).str.slice(start=28,stop=-2).to_string(index=False).strip()

   def FindXlCell(String):
     StringFound = FindXlCell(String, TFile.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1))
     if StringFound:
```

Comment: Using Pandas here isn't helping. I suggest you use openpyxl directly to read the file. openpyxl cells have an `offset` method that helps you find related celly by row and column.

Comment: I can find a string using Openpyxl?  Once the string is found offset can be used to look at the string 9 cells down?

Comment: Sure, you then call the offset method on the cell.